# Javascript project using Handsontable cannot find module on import

Tags: javascript, handsontable

I am trying to use the Handsontable seets component for VueJS project compiled with Webpack. But I am getting a 'cannot find module numbro' error, which occurs even if I dont import numbro in a module. I have installed all packages according to the package.json below using

```
npm install
```

package.json:

```
"dependencies": {
  "vue": "^2.1.10",
  "handsontable": "^0.31.1",
  "moment": "^2.18.1",
  "numbro": "^1.10.1",
  "pikaday": "^1.5.1",
  "vue-handsontable": "^0.0.2",
  "zeroclipboard": "^2.3.0"
},
```

As mentioned here: https://github.com/handsontable/handsontable/issues/3407 I added the four dependencies of Handsontable to the module loaders section of the webpack config file.

webpack.config.js

```
module: {
loaders: [
  {
    test: require.resolve('numbro'),
    loader: 'expose?numbro'
  },
  {
    test: require.resolve('moment'),
    loader: 'expose?moment'
  },
  {
    test: require.resolve('pikaday'),
    loader: 'expose?Pikaday'
  },
  {
    test: require.resolve('zeroclipboard'),
    loader: 'expose?ZeroClipboard'
  }]
```

TableView.vue

```
<template>
       <div id="hot-preview">
            <cool-table :data="data" :settings="{}"></cool-table>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import moment from 'moment'
import numbro from 'numbro'
import pikaday from 'pikaday'
import Zeroclipboard from 'zeroclipboard'
import Handsontable from 'handsontable'
import CoolTable from 'vue-handsontable'

export default {
  name: 'TablesView',
  data () {
    return {
      data: [
        ['', 'Kia', 'Nissan', 'Toyota', 'Honda'],
        ['2008', 10, 11, 12, 13],
        ['2009', 20, 11, 14, 13],
        ['2010', 30, 15, 12, 13]
      ]
    }
  },
  components: {
    CoolTable
  }
}
</script>
```

When I compile and run my VueJS project I get a console error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'numbro'
```

I can see a numbro folder with numbro.js in the node_modules folder. Any ideas as to what could be going wrong?

Comment: Check your network tab in Chrome Dev Tools on page load. Are you seeing a 404? If so, the issue is likely serving the file. If not, the issue is that your reference in the UI is likely referencing incorrectly.

Comment: @JohnVandivier It's not a 404 error, something to do with the webpack build setup I think.

Answer (score 0):

To get Handsontable to work I changed the webpack.config.js to use expose-loader:

```
loader: 'expose-loader?numbro'
```

Then I installed expose-loader

```
npm install expose-loader
```